# How to list everybody who shared an image on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I need to list everybody that shared one image and also re-shared.

How can I do this?

Comment: I mean I can do that handled. but isnt there a facebook api way? Or a app that do that for me?

Comment: Are you tried to use fql maybe like table can help you:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

Comment: he's asking for post "shares" not "likes"

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/165483) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)